# Where and when are the head DOM objects created when a javascript script is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The question is fairly straightforward.Suppose you run a javascript in html file with the following code:

```
document.write(...)
```

'...' can be anything syntactically acceptable.We know that this calls the write method of the document object. This means a document object is already made and loaded into the RAM for use. Here are the points I want be clear about:

1. Where is the document DOM object created? Knowing the DOM Model
   applies to multiple programming languages*, does that mean the
   interpreter for each language constructs a suitable
   document object before executing the script?Or is it constructed by
   the browser and loaded on demand by the script?

   ** the questions apply to equivalents of the given code for each programming language implementing the DOM*
2. When is the
   document object constructed? On demand or by default once the script
   runs?
3. What about the browser's DOM Objects like Navigator or Window? do the same
   answers of questions 1 and 2 apply to them too?

Comment: Does any of this matter?  Relevant DOM objects like `document` and `window` are created sometime before ANY Javascript in the page can run so they are always present when any script can possibly run.  What "multiple programming languages" are you talking about? What besides Javascript?

Comment: What has classic asp to do with this? It's a server side technology

Comment: DOM Model is generic and encompasses multiple programming languages. So the object-oriented implementation is also generic and thus are the questions.

Comment: Notice that the DOM model only specifies an interface - the dom is not necessarily constructed in the language you access it; in the case of browsers it's implemented in their native language and those JS objects are just a tiny wrappers around it.